# Retrofit API no estática

Tags: android, retrofit

Tengo una app en la que utilizo retrofit. Tengo una API creada de forma estática:

```
public class API {

private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NonNull Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                Credentials.basic("Usuario", "pass"));

        Request newRequest = builder.build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }

}).build();

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.miweb.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getApi(){
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Y llamo a la API con el codigo:

```
        HttpService service = API.getApi().create(HttpService.class);
```

Me gustaria poder pasar un usuario y contraseña y url de forma dinámica para el interceptor pero no consigo transformar mi API para que no sea estática.

Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Porque no utilizas Volley para tus peticiones http?, yo la uso y es excelente, va de lujo con las peticiones a mis apis externas

Comment: @Carlos Quintero Es mucho mejor y senzilla que Retrofit? La verdad es que soy bastante novato en programacion y me ha costado lo mio conseguir que las conexiones con retrofit me funcionaran o sea que migrar a Volley ahora me da un poco de pereza ;) Gracias por el aporte voy a explorar un poco a ver que tal Volley...

Comment: Pues si la veo mucho más sencilla, y dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo, la migración no sería tanto problema.